# Screen Cast Video Creation Software with Certain Features for OSX

Tags: osx, screen-recording

I am looking for a screen capture software with the following features

1. high quality video
2. record audio from computer and mic
3. ability to highlight mouse and mouse clicks
4. ability to show keyboard activity (e.g.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)
5. Ability to zoom in either while recording or after the fact

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) (for Mac, Windows, Linux) would perform the requirements you list.

1. The video quality isn't going to be higher than screen resolution unless you upscale it in post-processing, but the recording can be at a higher finished resolution (or lower) based on your configuration prior to recording start.
2. Audio recording is a feature listed in the program description, including external sources such as a microphone or aux input.
3. Highlighting mouse movement and clicks has to be implemented by an external program running simultaneously with your primary application. This feature is not available in OBS, but may be available as a plug-in (in the future). There are a number of add-on applications which cause your input via mouse to be highlighted independent of screen recording.
4. Keyboard activity is not a built-in feature, but is available as a plug-in and can be customized.
5. Referencing #3, if one can locate an add-on application for zoom while using the primary application, it will be recorded. The references I've found are for using Windows Magnifier or equivalent. From [AbilityNet](https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/macos-mojave-magnifying-screen), a reference for the on-board magnifier in the Mac:

[image: mac zoom panel]

I've used OBS Studio on Windows but have not had to pursue all of the features of your list.

Note also that OBS Studio is not a video editor. Any editing would have to be performed when the recording is completed, via an additional application.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:  https://screencast-o-matic.com/
It does everything on my list except for #4 which is not a big deal.
Also, I had a little trouble with getting the computer audio to work but there is a known workaround.  Only $4 / month (top-tier subscription) or less.